# neo4j browser paste multiple commands

Tags: import, neo4j

I'm trying to cut and paste multiple commands into the Neo4j browser.  When I paste and individual command it works fine.  When I paste multiple command sets all terminated by a `;` I encounter errors.

The commands are for example as follows:

```
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1000038'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='M5') create n1-    
[:STUDIES]->n2;
start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1000039'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='M7') create n1-   
[:STUDIES]->n2;
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid input 's': expected whitespace, comment or end of input (line 2, column 1)
"start n1=node:node_auto_index(id='1000040'),n2=node:node_auto_index(id='M15') create   
n1-[:STUDIES]->n2;"
 ^
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the moment, the Neo4j Browser only supports single statements, which may be multi-line. Execution of multiple statements is planned as a feature enhancement.

Cheers,
Andreas

Comment: Thanks!  I'll use the shell then to do the importing.

Comment: You can use the bin/neo4j-shell to connect to the currently running server. And paste your queries there. Or you go to http://localhost:7474/webadmin for the old web-ui

Answer (score 1):

In Neo4j 2.2.3 web interface, press Shift + Enter to generate multiple new lines and then enter your code. Then click on the run button on the right. For me, it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested with current Neo4j Browser (5.12) without APOC. Shift+Enter allows you to enter multiple lines and ending each command with a semicolon (;) allows you to run each command sequentially in a single cell.

In the following example all nodes of types A,B, and C can be detached and deleted using a single cell with the code:

```
MATCH(a:A) DETACH DELETE(a);
MATCH(b:B) DETACH DELETE(b);
MATCH(c:C) DETACH DELETE(c)
```

Just for completeness, it seems that Neo4j (with APOC) has support for multiple semicolon separated statement since version 4.1 ([reference](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/cypher-execution/cypher-multiple-statements/)):

> This procedure runs each semicolon separated statement and returns
> summary - currently no schema operations.

```
CALL apoc.cypher.runMany('cypher;\nstatements;',{params},[{statistics:true,timeout:10}])
```

Best,
Artur